# How to put space betwwen Vertically Aligned X-axis label in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have aligned my Xticks Vertically but all the labels are collapsed closely shown in the figure below:
[image]

This is my code for the above-shown Figure:

```
plt.plot(x_train.T,"*")

plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')

plt.show()
```

I want to put space between the x-axis labels. Any Hint?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try using a longer figure i.e., something like figsize=(16,6)

Comment: @Sheldore Thanks for your help but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can resize the font of the xticks:

```
plt.xticks(fontsize=6, rotation=90)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
plt.plot(x_train.T,"*")
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(30, 10)
plt.show()
```

Result:
[image]